# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :Column `LLb` must be length 4 (the number of rows) or one, not 5

Tags: linear-regression

I tried out the APA table functions (apa.reg.table, apa.cor.table) and first it worked out perfectly for the intercorrelations. But the apa.reg.table function ended in an error message I don't understand:

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :Column `LLb` must be length 4 (the number of rows) or one, not 5

I'm not very into R so the answers given in different forums didn't help me out.

That's how I tried it:
The data is given in a .sav table.

```
demographics <- lm(subjage ~ age_newsletter + sex + Educ_final + bildung_vorhanden, data=na.omit(BASE_II))
summary(demographics) # Model 1

phypsy <- lm(subjage ~ age_newsletter + sex + Educ_final + bildung_vorhanden + Morbiditätsindex_ohneHIV_Metastasen + optimismus, data=na.omit(BASE_II))
summary(physpsych) # Model 2

interaction <- lm(subjage ~ age_newsletter + sex + Educ_final + bildung_vorhanden + Morbiditätsindex_ohneHIV_Metastasen + optimismus + I(Morbiditätsindex_ohneHIV_Metastasen * optimismus), data=na.omit(BASE_II))
summary(interaction) # Model 3

apa.reg.table(demographics, phypsy, interaction, filename = "RegTable1.doc", prop.var.conf.level = 0.95)
```

after this didn't work out I tried it with an anova:

```
anova(demographics, phypsy, interaction)
```

With this it worked:

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: subjage ~ age_newsletter + sex + Educ_final + bildung_vorhanden
Model 2: subjage ~ age_newsletter + sex + Educ_final + bildung_vorhanden Morbiditätsindex_ohneHIV_Metastasen + optimismus
Model 3: subjage ~ age_newsletter + sex + Educ_final + bildung_vorhanden + 
Morbiditätsindex_ohneHIV_Metastasen + optimismus + I(Morbiditätsindex_ohneHIV_Metastasen * optimismus)

Res.Df   RSS Df Sum of Sq      F   Pr(>F)    
1    961 43638                                 
2    959 42659  2    978.25 10.984 1.92e-05 ***
3    958 42659  1      0.67  0.015   0.9025    
---Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

But I need every single variable given in the table not only the different models. So in my view it is the easiest way to take apa.reg.table because this is also already in APA how I need it. I'm not sure if it's right how I did it but maybe someone can help me with this. Thanks in advance!